# Garmin GPSMap 64S deleting waypoints?

Tags: qgis, gps, garmin

So I'll start off by saying I'm still in the rookie stages of GIS work.

But I have a GPSMap 64S and for work I had to go out and collect waypoints of an area. No problem, all was good and well, got back to the office and dragged them into QGIS 2.18 and they displayed perfectly. The problem starts when I removed the waypoints from the legend and then when I tried again nothing showed up. I went to the attribute table and there was nothing. The I went into the GPS and the waypoints were no longer on the device either. They seemed to just disappear?

Comment: do use a sd card on your gps device?

Comment: No Im not using one.